# Simple TypeScript constructor variables interpreted as services (AngularJS with TypeScript)

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have a simple controller and interface set up with TypeScript.

```
module signup { 

    // define signup interface for signup home controller
    interface ISignupCredentials {
        firstName: string;
        companyEmail: string;
        password: string;
    }

    export class SignupCtrl implements ISignupCredentials {

        static IID = "SignupCtrl";          
        constructor(public firstName: string,
                    public companyEmail: string,
                    public password: string) {                      

                    }                   
    }

    angular
        .module("signup", [])
        .controller(SignupCtrl.IID, SignupCtrl)     

}
```

I'm getting this error:

[image]

It looks like Angular thinks these are services, but I'm not sure why. I'm  missing something completely here, but I can't see what it is. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Could it be that you're not exporting that module? Try `export module signup` or even just remove that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that controller construct method is indeed defines services, because it's called by Angular with necessary dependencies passed in. You don't construct controller instances manually.

Proper interface implementation would be:

```
// define signup interface for signup home controller
interface ISignupCredentials {
    firstName: string;
    companyEmail: string;
    password: string;
}

export class SignupCtrl implements ISignupCredentials {

    static IID = "SignupCtrl";

    firstName: string;
    companyEmail: string;
    password: string;

    constructor() {
        // ...
    }
}

angular
    .module("signup", [])
    .controller(SignupCtrl.IID, SignupCtrl)
```

Comment: Perfect, this worked! Thank you for the explanation :)